# Custom Validator and @Validate

Tags: java, spring, validation

I will show you some code and then I will ask a question.

**AccountValidator.java**

```
package com.goode.validator;

import com.goode.business.Account;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@Component
public class AccountValidator implements Validator {

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
    return Account.class.equals(clazz);
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    Account account = (Account) target;

    if(account.getUsername() == null || account.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
      errors.rejectValue("username", "empty username");
    }

  }

  public void validateId(Object target, Errors errors) {
    Account account = (Account) target;

    if(account.getId() == 1) {
      errors.rejectValue("id", "bad ID");
    }

  }
}
```

**AccountController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController extends BaseController<Account, AccountService> {

  @Autowired
  private AccountService accountService;

  @Autowired
  private AccountValidator accountValidator;

  @InitBinder
  protected void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder)
  {
    binder.addValidators(accountValidator);
  }

  @PostMapping("/register")
  public ResponseEntity<?> register(HttpServletRequest request, @Validated(Account.ValidationStepOne.class) @RequestBody Account account, BindingResult result) {
    super.initializeService(accountService);

    //accountValidator.validateId(account, result);

    if(result.hasErrors()){
      return ErrorMessage.send(result.getFieldError().getCode(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

In **Account.java** I have some validators e.g. @NotNull -> @Validate checks for me fields -> works perfect.
But now I want to add some custom validators so I create **AccountValidator** and I put some validation to **validate** method and created @InitBinder -> if **username** is empty or null this *result* will show me error -> that works good.
But I created another validate method - **validateId**. If I uncomment this line:

```
accountValidator.validateId(account, result);
```

validator will work good and result will show error but is it possible to do something with @InitBinder to avoid using **validateId** method? I would like to call to **validateId** automatically like validate method. Is it possible?

Happy Day of the Programmer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validateId automatically, you should call validateId inside validate method.

```
@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
   Account account = (Account) target;

   if(account.getUsername() == null || account.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
    errors.rejectValue("username", "empty username");
   }
  validateId(account, errors);
}
```